# Resend 2Factor Authentication verification code (Laravel with Nexmo)

Tags: laravel, vonage

I have a laravel app with integrated with 2 factor authentication using Nexmo API . I have manage to verify the code in the login process . so now i need to re-send the verification again ..

I already followed this article and called same method again but it's not working

```
https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2017/07/26/2fa-logins-laravel-nexmo-dr/
```

Here is Re-Send Button

```
<a href="{{ route('reverify') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Re-Verify</a>
```

Here is the route

```
Route::get('/reverify', 'Auth\LoginController@reauthenticated')->name('reverify');
```

Here is the Re-Send Code

```
public function reauthenticated(Authenticatable $user)
    {
          $verification = Nexmo::verify()->start([
            'number' => $user->phone_number,
            'brand'  => 'Ezy verification'
        ]);
        $request->session()->put('verify:request_id', $verification->getRequestId());

        return redirect('verify');

    }
```

So I just need to know how can I resend the verification code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the use case here. You Verify a user's phone number, why do you need to send the verification again? Can you say what about the code above doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: @LornaMitchell .. On the first time somehow verfication doesn't send .. users need an option to resend again. that's why i'm asking

Comment: If you're integrated with Verify API then it sends the codes multiple times until the user is confirmed anyway. I think by default the user gets an SMS followed by two phone calls with a spoken pin a few minutes apart. Once the process has timed out (five minutes after the last call), you can just start the process again the same way you started it the first time. Does this help or am I missing the point?

Comment: Or Is there any way  to change the default expire time 5 Minutes to 1 Minute

Comment: You can set the `next_event_wait` value to make each stage happen sooner. If the problem is that the SMS doesn't send and you just want phone calls, you can set the `workflow_id` field. There's more information on the Nexmo developer portal that I hope will help https://developer.nexmo.com - you can also trigger the next verification stage at any time, check the API reference or the examples here https://developer.nexmo.com/verify/code-snippets/trigger-next-verification-process

Comment: How to add next_event_wait to above code .. Can you explain

Comment: it's an API parameter, so you can send it to `start()` alongside `number` and `brand` parameters.